# Colocar en NULL los valores duplicados de una consulta LEFT JOIN Msql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, join

Tengo 2 tablas.

La primera devuelve el numero de pedido y los tiempos de dos estados

```
Pedido     TiempoPreparar     TiempoAsignar
-------------------------------------------
P001         10                9
P002         20                5
P003         30                7
```

La segunda, devuelve los tiempos de 2 estados distintos:

```html
Pedido     TiempoEmpacar  TiempoEnruta
-------------------------------------------
P001         23                10
P001         14                21
P002         34                6
P003         16                5
P003         22                12
```

En la tabla 2 puede existir varios registros para un solo pedido.

Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta:

```
select A.*,B.TiempoEmpacar, TiempoEnruta 
from tabla1 A 
left join tabla2 B
on A.pedido = B.pedido
```

Que devuelve esto

```
Pedido TiempoPreparar TiempoAsignar TiempoEmpacar TiempoEnRuta
-------------------------------------------------------------
P001        10             9              23           10
P001        10             9              14           21
P002        20             5              34           6
P003        30             7              16           5
P003        30             7              22           12
```

Pero necesito que para los valores duplicados, muestre NULL, algo así:

```html
Pedido TiempoPreparar TiempoAsignar TiempoEmpacar TiempoEnRuta
-------------------------------------------------------------
P001        10             9              23           10
P001        NULL           NULL           14           21
P002        20             5              34           6
P003        30             7              16           5
P003        NULL           NULL           22           12
```

Esa data la llevo a Quicksight (herramienta de reporting), donde creo un Dashboard, ahi tengo la opción de realizar PROMEDIOS, pero si llevo data duplicada la tomará en cuenta, y es lo que quiero evitar.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Has probado el `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Si estimado y devuelve lo mismo

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que probaste con `select distinct` porque según lo que veo eso debería resolver tu problema.

Comment: Estas usando MySQL ó Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Estoy usando Mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es para evitar repetidos has un `union` en lugar de un `join`

```
SELECT
    Pedido,
    TiempoPreparar,
    TiempoAsignar,
    null as TiempoEmpacar,
    null as TiempoEnruta
FROM tabla1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Pedido,
    null as TiempoPreparar,
    null as TiempoAsignar,
    TiempoEmpacar,
    TiempoEnruta
FROM tabla2
ORDER BY Pedido;
```

Comment: Fue la solución más rápida y fácil de aplicar, aunque visualmente no es lo optimo. Pero como en realidad solo necesitaba q la data no este duplicada para luego realizar cálculos, me sirvió montón. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Esto seguramente tenga algún error de sintaxis, pero tal vez pueda ayudarte a encaminar tu idea

```
SELECT * --Aquí los campos que te interese mostrar
FROM tabla1 A
INNER JOIN( select B.pedido, SUM(B.TiempoEmpacar), SUM(TiempoEnruta )
            from tabla2 B 
            GROUP BY B.pedido) on A.pedido = pedido
```

En la subconsulta sumamos los tiempos y los agrupamos por pedido y en la consulta principal mostramos los tiempos ya agrupados

Comment: en lugar de suma, seria sacar el promedio verdad?

Comment: @FacundoInsua cierto, sería un AVG() Aunque ahora no recuerdo cual era la función correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr el resultado esperado, basado en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652359/525826) de SO en ingles.

Podrias realizar subconsultas para obtener las filas de interes de la tabla2 estableciendo un seudo-orden en base al `TiempoEmpacar` y `TiempoEnruta`:

- Asumiendo `TiempoEnruta` menores a 1000
- Para el `join` con `tabla1`, utilizar aquella fila con menor `TiempoEmpacar` y `TiempoEnruta` determinado por la expresion

  ```
  t.TiempoEmpacar * 1000 + t.TiempoEnruta
  ```
- Luego unir los filas restantes de `tabla2`

Quedando una consulta bastante extensa:

```
select A.*, B.TiempoEmpacar, B.TiempoEnruta 
from tabla1 A
left join (
  select t.Pedido, t.TiempoEmpacar, t.TiempoEnruta
  from tabla2 t join tabla2 tt
  on t.Pedido = tt.Pedido
  and t.TiempoEmpacar * 1000 + t.TiempoEnruta <= tt.TiempoEmpacar * 1000 + tt.TiempoEnruta
  group by t.Pedido, t.TiempoEmpacar, t.TiempoEnRuta
  having count(*) = 1
) B
on A.pedido = B.pedido

union

select t.Pedido, null, null, t.TiempoEmpacar, t.TiempoEnruta
from tabla2 t join tabla2 tt
on t.Pedido = tt.Pedido
and t.TiempoEmpacar * 1000 + t.TiempoEnruta <= tt.TiempoEmpacar * 1000 + tt.TiempoEnruta
group by t.Pedido, t.TiempoEmpacar, t.TiempoEnRuta
having count(*) > 1

order by pedido;
```

Puedes probar lo anterior en [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d95bb/13)

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema interesante, en la siguiente consulta se puede obtener el resultado que buscas, usa una variable de usuario para identificar el primer pedido y realiza el join usandolo.
Esta consulta asume que la tabla2 esta ordenada por numero de pedido, de no ser asi haria falta una subconsulta que la ordenara.

```
  SELECT B.pedido,
         A.TiempoPreparar,
         A.TiempoAsignar,
         B.tiempoEmpacar,
         B.TiempoEnruta
    FROM tabla1 A RIGHT JOIN 
       ( SELECT pedido,
                IF(@pedido = pedido, NULL, @pedido:= pedido) primerPedido,
                TiempoEmpacar,
                TiempoEnruta 
           FROM tabla2
              ) B ON  A.pedido = B.pedido
                  AND B.primerPedido IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY B.pedido,A.Pedido DESC;
```